# how to insert html tag inside sql in Liquibase migration?

Tags: database, grails, migration, liquibase

I need to update my data that have html tag inside so wrote this on liquibase

```
<sql> update table_something set table_content = " something <br/> in the next line " </sql>
```

it apparently doesn't work on liquibase ( i got loooong errors .. and meaningless). I tried to remove `<br/>` and it works.

my question is, is it possible to insert / update something that contains xml tag in Liquibase ?

I am using liquibase 1.9.3 with Grails 1.1.1

edited: forgot to set code sample tag in my examples.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Could you please explain a bit more what your setting is? Are you using liquibase XML directly for defining your changesets, or do you use the DSL provided by the autobase grails plugin? Is your "update .." something you try to execute in a custom sql refactoring (http://www.liquibase.org/manual/custom_sql)?

Comment: sorry i was forgot to add code formatting in my example.

i was trying to execute a migration that contains "sql" commands and inside i put a html/xml tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As the liquibase author mentions [here](http://liquibase.org/forum/index.php?topic=67.0) you'll need to add CDATA section inside <sql>.

In your particular example that would become:

```
<sql><![CDATA[ update table_something set table_content = " something <br/> in the next line " ]]></sql>
```

Answer (score 8):

Even better not to use a `<sql>` tag at all (I added the where clause ...):

```
<changeSet author="author" id="table_something_1">
    <update tableName="table_something">
        <column name="table_content"><![CDATA[ something <br/> in the next line ]]></column>
        <where>id=1</where>
    </update>
    <rollback />
</changeSet>
```